# How do I get text from UITextField in an UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to add a new cell to a tableview, and pop up an alert with a UITextField to allow the user to input the title they wish to give the new cell. I have code to pop up an alert with a UITextField when the "+" button is pressed, and the code to add a new cell, however I don't know how to get the text from the UITextField to insert it into the cell's title.

This is my code to pop up the alert:

```
UIAlertView* alertPopUp = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
 [alertPopUp setDelegate:self];
 [alertPopUp setTitle:@"Enter event title"];
 [alertPopUp setMessage:@" "];
 [alertPopUp addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
 [alertPopUp addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

 UITextField * eventNameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
 [eventNameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 [alertPopUp addSubview:eventNameField];
 [alertPopUp show];
```

and my alertView action is:

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
 if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
  return;
 }
 else if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {

 }

}
```

What can I do to get the text from eventNameField when "Ok" is pressed and add it to a mutablearray named eventList? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the tag on eventNameField to something meaningful

```
eventNameField.tag = 1001;
```

Then inside of the alertViewDelegate you can get the TextField by using - [UIView viewWithTag:]

```
UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)[alertView viewWithTag:1001];
```

Answer (score 1):

`eventNameField.text` should give you the value

```
//declare the array
NSMutableArray* eventList = [NSMutableArray array];

//set its value
[eventList addObject:eventNameField.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

DHamrick probably has the better solution, but found one more that could work.

You can get all the subviews inside alertView with [alertView subviews] (returns a NSCFArray), then you just have to find the one that is of class UITextField, in your case you could get it with:

```
[[[alertView subviews] objectAtIndex:4] text]
```

Comment: This will work in the current iOS version, but could be broken in a future version if they change the number of subviews in a UIAlertView. It's a good idea though.

Comment: You could check the Class of the object returned, if it is of class UITextField that it should be your UITextField (if Apple doesnt't add one in future SDK as well:)

Answer (score 0):

The old answers don't take advantage of changes in UIAlertView.

In iOS 5 and beyond, there is an easier way of using UITextfield on an alert view:

```
   UIAlertView *alertPopUp = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter event title" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    alertPopUp.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    self.alertTextField = [message textFieldAtIndex:0];
    self.alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    alertPopUp.delegate = self;
    [alertPopUp show];
    [self.alertTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

where alertTextField was set up like this:

```
@propery (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *alertTextField;
```

Then you can access alertTextField in your delegate response:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
   if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
       return;
   }
   else if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {
       NSLog(@"your text string is %@", self.alertTextField.text);
   }
}
```

You could also just give the alertView a unique tag, and compare tag numbers, rather than save a reference to it using @property.